# GLFW Hat & Hat States

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, glfw

Basic question alert!

What is a joystick hat and joystick hat state in GLFW? I know that there are axis and buttons but I thought that is all a controller was comprised of, so I am confused up to whatever it could be.

I am using the latest version of GLFW and am currently implementing a Joystick class to interface with any given joystick.

Comment: Are you asking what *actually* is a [joystick hat](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/what-is-a-hat-switch-on-a-joystick)?

Answer (score 0):

According to the document, the joystick state has states below and can be combined:

```
GLFW_HAT_CENTERED   0
GLFW_HAT_UP     1
GLFW_HAT_RIGHT  2
GLFW_HAT_DOWN   4
GLFW_HAT_LEFT   8
GLFW_HAT_RIGHT_UP   
GLFW_HAT_RIGHT_DOWN 
GLFW_HAT_LEFT_UP    
GLFW_HAT_LEFT_DOWN
```

In addition, you could browse pictures of some commonly used controllers.

Comment: I read that, but what does all of that translates to the physical controller with a typical button and axis mapping?